# Lease with intent to purchase a vehicle

Tags: car, auto-loan, auto-leasing

I am in the market for my first new vehicle ever. It will be a minivan for our growing family and we ideally plan to keep it forever. That being said, none of my vehicles have ever cost more than $15k so the prospect of making payments on a $40k+ purchase is intimidating. A friend suggested I consider starting off by leasing the vehicle and then purchasing at lease end to spread out the payments and make them cheaper. This makes sense to me, since we plan to keep it until it dies. I understand we will be paying on the vehicle longer overall but it will allow us to spend less money per month on a vehicle in case other emergencies pop up. I also understand there may be a disposition fee at the end of the lease to consider.

Can someone more financially savvy than myself tell me whether this is good advice? Is there anything I should consider here that I haven’t?

Comment: Does the leasing contract limit how many miles you are allowed to drive per year?

Comment: Yes, 10k miles a year I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends entirely on terms of the lease but it in most case a lease is not a good idea.

1. Car dealers are in the business of not offering you the best deal. Complicated lease terms are a good way to do this. Google "four square car sales method" for some examples on how this works. See for example https://www.consumerreports.org/consumerist/dealerships-rip-you-off-with-the-four-square-heres-how-to-beat-it/
2. If you ran afoul any term of the lease (mileage, scratch & dent) the will charge you an arm and a leg for it.

Typically you are much better off separating the financing and the car purchase process. This way you bring cold hard cash to the negotiating table and the dealers have less chances to obfuscate the actual terms.

Comment: Good advice.  Nicely done.

Comment: On your last point. It is good advice to bring your own financing and do a cash deal. But don't tell the dealership that until you have a firm quote on the car and your trade-in. If they are expecting to make some money off the financing they might not be so aggressive negotiating the price of the car.  Just tell them you are undecided about financing until the very end.

Comment: You don't have to do the trade-in at the dealer. I have gotten a guaranteed quote for the trade-in at another place before I go to the dealer I am going to buy the car from.

Comment: For 2, if you buy the vehicle at the end of the lease you generally avoid charges for dings or mileage.  Those charges are to compensate the dealer for the lower than expected value of the car at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If the current state price of used cars wasn't through the roof because of chip shortages for new cars, I would suggest skip the lease years and just purchase a used car coming off lease. You would be getting a car that was 2 or three years old, that has gone through the steepest part of depreciation curve.

My credit union offers loans for up to 84 months, so that can keep the monthly cost somewhat lower.

Negotiation of the lease terms is more complex then the ones for a straight up purchase. Being able to skip the lease negotiation would be a plus. Being able to focus on the purchase price by handling the loan approval process, and the trade-in agreement before you even go to the dealer, can make the purchase price negotiation less of a shell game.

Some banks, credit unions,insurance companies, auto clubs, or warehouse stores offer a buyers service for new and used cars that can help you determine an appropriate value. That can help set a goal for the negotiation before you even go to the dealership.

The chip shortage is driving the price of both new and used cars through the roof. There are cases where 3 years old cars are selling for more than their original purchase price. If that is normal, it might be best to wait out the current shortages.

Comment: 4 years ago my wife wanted a new car. We were at an odd point of MAGI with a high tax cost to add a cash purchase to the budget. Given the choice of buying vs leasing, there was little difference in total cost if we assumed a purchase at the end of the 3 years. But. I promised her if she hated the car, she could move on. (effectively a Put Option). Last year, we bought my daughter a similar car. same 3 years old. 1/2 the price of the new car, with just 18,000 miles.  Shortage aside, your answer is 100% perfect. 1/2 price with over 80% of useful life left.

Comment: The current cost of used vehicles was actually the only reason I was considering new. Used vehicles like mentioned here are going for only $3-4k less than new, so I was kind of wondering why bother going the used route right now. However, both the posted answers have made me decide to try to get by on our current vehicles until things are a little bit back to normal and then looking at the used market again.